# How to rebase in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How can I do the following in the IntelliJ IDEA?

```
$ git checkout my-local-branch
$ git rebase master -i
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way: just open the git console in intellij and type it.

Otherwise, the `Git Integration` plugin in intellij, at least from version 8.1, has a `Rebase onto` function.

(accessible at the bottom right of your screen, where it says "Git: " - click, get up the "branches" popup, choose a branch).

Edit: there's also a dialog accessible via the intellij menu: VCS -> Git -> Rebase...

Documentation:

- [IntelliJ 2016.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/rebasing-branches.html?origin=old_help)
- [IntelliJ 2021.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#rebase-branch)

Answer (score 9):

go to VCS -> Git _> rebase

and then fill the dialog with relavent details

```
git Root : should be your local path <br/>
Branch   : your working branch(topic branch) </br>
Onto     : topic branch <br/>
From     : master branch
```

The interactive option can be used for normal rebase which will ignore merge commits.

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I looked for when finding this thread.  It's easy to find the Rebase dialog in IntelliJ, but it's not obvious how these fields relate to `git rebase master`.

Comment: The user interface of the IntelliJ IDEA changed. This answer could be improved by updating it.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ IDEA UI has changed. For version 2020.2.3, it's like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Menu `VCS -> Git -> Rebase...`

Answer (score 1):

I think UI is changed. I don't know when it is changed but I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.1. Accessing it is the same via menu `VCS -> Git -> Rebase...`

[image: IntelliJ Git Rebease]